# Leaflet popups usually open and immediately close when using mobile/touchscreen device

Tags: leaflet

I've been building a wiki for golf courses, and I'm now trying to add a map to the homepage. Everything seems to work just fine, unless it's on a touch screen, where, most of the time, but not always, the popups immediately close upon clicking. I have already gone through [Leaflet popup immediately closing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401325), but it offers little advice.

The code is live on the site i'm working on: http://www.golfcourse.wiki

The problem exists for me on both on ios and MacOS, firefox and chrome (even in the desktop testing frameworks if touch simulation is turned on. Note comment below: @TomazicM could not replicate on android/windows Chrome browser.

The framework is flask + jinja2, here is the relevant code:

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map img {
        {# this needs to be added beause somewhere up the chain imgs have padding #}
        padding: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }
    .course_marker {
        border: solid 1px green;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .incomplete_course_marker{
        border: solid 1px green;
        border-radius: 50%;
        filter: saturate(25%);
    }
    .popup,
    .popup_anchor:link
    .popup_anchor:visited {
        color: rgb(var(--light-mode-text-main));
        background: rgb(var(--light-mode-main-main));
    }

    .leaflet-popup-pane {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        .leaflet-popup-tip,
        .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
        .popup,
        .popup_anchor:link,
        .popup_anchor:visited {
            color: rgb(var(--dark-mode-text-main));
            background: rgb(var(--dark-mode-background-main));
        }
        .popup:hover {
            background:     rgba(var(--color-lighten), 0.6);
        }

    }
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
    // replace "toner" here with "terrain" or "watercolor"
    let layer = new L.StamenTileLayer("toner-lite", {detectRetina: true});
    let map = new L.Map("map", {
        center: new L.LatLng(
            {{ user_lat_long[0] | float }},
            {{ user_lat_long[1] | float }}
            ),
        zoom: 11,
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);

    let myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: '/favicon.ico',
        iconSize: [25, 25],
        //iconAnchor: [22, 94],
        //popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
        //shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
        //shadowSize: [68, 95],
        //shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
    });

    {% for course in courses %}
        var marker = L.marker(
            [{{ course.index.lat }}, {{ course.index.long }}],
            {icon: myIcon},
        );

        var course_content =
            `
            <section class="popup"
                style="
                    padding: 1px;
                    margin: 0 20px 3px 0;
                ">
                <a  class="popup_anchor"
                    href="${ "{{ url_for('course_page', unique_path=course.unique_path) }}" }"
                    data-button-like="true"
                    data-clickable="true"
                    data-remove-anchor-text-format="main"
                    data-required-child-div-for-text-alignment="true"
                    style="
                        ${ "{% if course.index.incomplete %}opacity: 50%;{%else %}{% endif %}" }
                        border: none;
                    ">
                    <div>${ "{{ course.name}}" }</div>
                    <section
                        style="
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: column;
                            font-size: 66%;
                            text-align: left;
                        ">
                        <div>${ "{{ course.facts.city }}" }, ${ "{{ course.facts.country }}" }</div>
                        <div>${ "{{ course.facts.num_holes }}" } Hole, Par ${ "{{ course.handicaps.get(course.index.hardest_handicap_id).par }}" }</div>
                        <div>${ "{{ course.index.longest_tee.total }}" } ${ "{{ course.index.longest_tee.units }}" }</div>
                    </section>
                </a>
            </section>
            `;

        var popup = L.popup({
            setLatLng: marker.getLatLng(),
            closeOnClick: false,
            closeButton: true,
        }).setContent(course_content);

        marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
        marker.addTo(map);
        {% if course.index.incomplete %}
            marker._icon.classList.add("incomplete_course_marker");
        {% else %}
            marker._icon.classList.add("course_marker");
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</script>
```

I obviously plan on refactoring the sporadic CSS once it's up and running.

Comment: A could not replicate this behavior for http://www.golfcourse.wiki site on mobile phone (Android 8, Chrome), neither on Windows Chrome touch simulation.

Comment: I'm definitely getting the problem using an iphone 7 and MacOS Catalina (firefox & chrome touch simulations)... perhaps it's an apple specific issue

Comment: this may be a known bug: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255

Comment: Or a different bug. I would suggest you report it to Leaflet github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think it has something todo with this [Github issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7255) then you can try to disable `tap` in while map creation:

```
 let map = new L.Map("map", {
        center: new L.LatLng(
            {{ user_lat_long[0] | float }},
            {{ user_lat_long[1] | float }}
            ),
        zoom: 11,
tap: false
    });
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much!